# Validation on Regex in time format

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

i have a search string :

```
var searchString = "the times are 21:06 , 03-25 , 16:565";
```

then i use regex to get the valid times only,

like this :

```
var reg = /\d{2}[:-]\d{2}/gi
```

but when i do `alert(search.match(reg));` the output is :

```
21:06,03-25,16:56
```

`16:56` should not display because in my `searchString` it is `16:565`
i'm stuck on how to prevent the last value to be caught on my regex.

How to achieve the validation i wanted?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add word boundaries (`\b`) to your regular expression :

```
var reg = /\b\d{2}[:-]\d{2}\b/gi;
```

Answer (score 2):

For exact time match(24 hour format),

```
\b(?:0[1-9]|1[1-9]|2[0123])[:-](?:0[1-9]|[1-5][0-9]|00)\b
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/cB1vC5/2)